# Ruby on Rails - Couldn't find Post with 'id'=string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, posts

Having trouble passing a string as a parameter instead of an ID. I keep getting hit with "Couldn't find Post with 'id'=stack".

routes.rb makes a GET request for a :short_url in the redirect controller.

```
get '/:short_url' => 'posts#redirect'
resources :posts
```

post_controller.rb is finding the params[:short_url] of the in the post.

```
def redirect
    @post = Post.find(params[:short_url])
    redirect_to @post.(params[:url])
end
```

The view is simply an anchor tag with a @post.each do |post| loop.

```
    <a class="item" target="_blank" href="<%= post.short_url %">
      <div>Short URL</div>
      <%= post.short_url %>
    </a>
```

Not sure if I'm calling the parameter at the routes or controller level incorrectly.

Comment: "stack" in 'id'=stack is just an example of a string that's being passed.

Comment: you should use the `@post = Post.find_by_short_url(params[:short_url])` syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `find` method finds a record based on the `id`(which is an integer). If you want to lookup a table based on any other field(in your case, `short_url`), you need to use the `find_by` method.

You're getting the error `Couldn't find Post with 'id'=stack` as `ActiveRecord` is looking up the `posts` table for an `id` of `stack` which does not exist. Try

```
@post = Post.find_by(short_url: params[:short_url])
redirect_to @post
```

Comment: Thanks Arun! I used "puts" on the terminal to troubleshoot and I realized I needed to use .find_by instead of .find . Much appreciate it.